# jquery setinterval not working no console error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im trying to add and remove class every 1 second but its now working and there is no console error

im actually trying to change one of my menu items color and background color to make attention i cant solve :(

**there is my jquery html and css code**

**jquery**

```
function ds1() {
    $("#h").addClass("ds");
};

function ds2() {
    $("#h").removeClass("ds");
};

function ds() {
    if ( $("#h").css("color") == ("#000000") ){
        $("#h").addClass("ds");
    }else{
        $("#h").removeClass("ds");
    }
};

setInterval(ds , 1000);
```

**html**

```
<ul id="alt_menu2">
<li><a href="#" class="anasayfa">Ana sayfa</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="modlar">Modlar</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="kaynakpaketleri">Kaynak paketleri</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="hariatalar">Haritalar</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="kendinyap">Kendin yap</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="heraypremium" id="h">Her ay premium</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="yardim">Yardım</a></li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
#alt_menu2{
    width: 1020px;
    height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
}

#alt_menu2 li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    border-color: #cccccc;
}

#alt_menu2 li a,.heraypremium{
    padding: 16px 18px 15px 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    /*transition: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s
    -o-transition: 0.5s;*/
}

#alt_menu2 li a:hover{
    padding: 12px 18px 15px 17px;
    border-width: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    border-style: solid;
}

.ds{
    background-color: #303030 !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;

}
```

Comment: You need to pass a function to `setInterval`, not the result of a function... `setInterval(ds, 1000)`.

Comment: actually i know that wrong but i tried ds than i said maybe ds() is true and forgot to remove before sharing there :D

Comment: In addition to @Phil 's fix, you might want to take a look at `.toggleClass()` http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: how can i edit my question im just new in stackoverflow

Comment: @sdasdas http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37824113/edit

Comment: @mpf82 its worked thx

Comment: @sdasdas you're welcome. A different approach could have been to use `.hasClass()` instead of checking the color, but IMHO, `.toggleClass()` is better in this case.

Comment: `css('color')` won't return a hex value. Will be an `rgb` or `rgba` depending on browser

Answer (score 0):

when do ds() with the parentheses, you're actually calling the action then.

try

```
setInterval(function(){console.log('interval ran')},1000) //in your case, you already have a function you want to call so

setInterval(ds,1000);
```